# Вертикальное выравнивание картинки по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть блок в котором есть картинка:

```css
.equipment_box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:0 0 35px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.equipment_box img {
    width: 250px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
  <div class="equipment_box">
    <a href="/shop?category=1&subcategory=5"><img style="display: inline-block;" src="../images/sivalku.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="equipment_box-title">drill</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы независимо от размера картинки, картинка всегда была в середине блока?

Answer (score 2):

Вроде все итак по центру:

```css
.equipment_box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:0 0 35px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
    text-align: center;
  
  
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /*  Для наглядности примера */
}

.equipment_box a {
  display: block;
}

.equipment_box img {
    width: 250px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2" >
  <div class="equipment_box">
    <a href="/shop?category=1&subcategory=5">
      <img style="display: inline-block;" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x300/000/fff" alt="">
      <div class="equipment_box-title">drill</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно добавить `.equipment_box { ... align-items: center; align-content: center; justify-content: center; ... }` для выравнивания содержимого по центру силами `flex`.

А вообще уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, только нужно знать высоту и ширину картинки.

```css
.equipment_box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.equipment_box img {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 240px/2);
  right: calc(50% - 320px/2);
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <div class="equipment_box">
    <a href="/shop?category=1&subcategory=5"><img style="display: inline-block;" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```